# Show Data Method

Tags: java, variables, methods, printing, println

Hey sorry for the bad formatting. I am in a java class and don't know how to pass the bank account data into one show value method if someone could help that would be great!what i am not understanding is how to call the same method but pass different bank accounts into it.I thought i could just call showData(a); but this was not working. Please help!!

```
 `/**
 * Write a description of class TestBankAccount here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class TestBankAccount
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   int AccountNumber;
      String name;
      double balance;
      double NewBalance;

      bankAccount newAccount = new bankAccount();
      newAccount = getData(newAccount);



      bankAccount newAccount2 = new bankAccount();
      newAccount2 = getData(newAccount);

      bankAccount newAccount3 = new bankAccount();
      newAccount3 = getData(newAccount);

      bankAccount newAccount4 = new bankAccount();  

    }
    public static bankAccount getData(bankAccount s)
    {
        int AccountNum;
        String ownerName;
        double AccountBalance;

        Scanner stan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Account Number ");
        AccountNum = stan.nextInt();
        stan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter owner name ");
        ownerName = stan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Account Balance: ");
        AccountBalance = stan.nextDouble();
        s.setAccountNumber(AccountNum);
        s.setName(ownerName);
        s.setBalance(AccountBalance);
        s.setNewBalance(AccountBalance);
        return s;

        }
        public static void showData(bankAccount a)
        {
          System.out.println("The account number is: ");
      System.out.println(a.getAccountNumber());
      System.out.println("The owner name is:  ");
      System.out.println(a.getName());
      System.out.println("The balance is: ");
      System.out.println(a.getNewBalance());
      System.out.println(a.explanation());    
    }
    }`
```

Comment: Please work on your punctuation skills. Why do you excuse for bad formatting, you could have formatted the post? Regarding your question - just carefully look at your code...

Comment: I have been looking at my code just please help lead me towards what I need to do I am so stuck. And about the formatting I am just really unfamiliar with the website and need help quickly sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

```
bankAccount newAccount = new bankAccount();
newAccount = getData(newAccount);
bankAccount newAccount2 = new bankAccount();
newAccount2 = getData(newAccount);
bankAccount newAccount3 = new bankAccount();
newAccount3 = getData(newAccount);
bankAccount newAccount4 = new bankAccount();  
newAccount4 = getData(newAccount);
```

You are passing the same bank account always. In you method you set everything to that account. hence it is a problem.

Either change this to

```
bankAccount newAccount = new bankAccount();
newAccount = getData(newAccount);
bankAccount newAccount2 = new bankAccount();
newAccount2 = getData(newAccount2);
bankAccount newAccount3 = new bankAccount();
newAccount3 = getData(newAccount3);
bankAccount newAccount4 = new bankAccount();  
newAccount4 = getData(newAccount4);
```

Or change you method to not take in a parameter.

Like this:

```
public static bankAccount getData()
{
    Scanner stan = new Scanner(System.in);
    bankAccount s = new bankAccount(); 
    System.out.print("Enter Account Number ");
    s.setAccountNumber(stan.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Enter Account Balance: ");
    As.setBalance(stan.nextDouble());
    System.out.print("Enter owner name ");
    s.setName(stan.nextLine());
    return s;
}
```

Then change your main code to :

```
bankAccount newAccount = getData();
bankAccount newAccount2 = getData();
bankAccount newAccount3 = getData();
bankAccount newAccount4 = getData();
```